# How to download a video file from a link in phonegap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

Let suppose i have an .mp4 vedio on server. i want to download it in android phone, how i can do it.. Please guide me with some code

```
<script>
function downloadImage(url,fileName){
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
fileTransfer.download(
    url,
    window.rootFS.fullPath+ "/" + fileName,
    function(entry) {
        alert(\"download complete: \" + entry.fullPath);
    },
    function(error) {
        alert(\"download error\"+JSON.stringify(error));
    }
);
```

}